# Electors: Are Their Identities Public Information?

Tags: united-states, electoral-college

Is the identity of each elector who will vote in December available to the public? Or would it be a state by state process to get their identities? (I have sent message to electoral.college@nara.gov - no answer as of yet - their response is below)

Comment: We do not yet have the names of the electors.  We will not receive them until the States (and District of Columbia (DC)) submit their Certificates of Ascertainment. We will post images of these Certificates as we receive them.  In the meantime, you can reach out to each State and DC to request the names of their electors.This information can be found by accessing the National Association of Secretaries of State website atwww.nass.org. (fr. Electoral.college@nara.gov)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the names of the electors for each state and party are public information. You can find the canonical lists on the websites of the respective state governments. Here [the one for California](http://elections.cdn.sos.ca.gov/statewide-elections/2016-general/pres-elector-list.pdf) and here [the one for Idaho](http://www.sos.idaho.gov/ELECT/candidat/2016/2016_General_List_FederalCandidates.pdf), for example.

There is also [an aggregated list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_presidential_electors,_2016) (which is unfortunately missing a few states).

Comment: That's unfortunate given the lunacy that seems to be happening now.

Comment: Your Wikipedia link is just the Idaho list again.

Comment: Are they there any states that DON'T give the names of the electors on the ballots?